Qt for Android arm64-v8a AVD can't start
I've learned from another answer, AVD for arm64-v8a can only support SDK under 28 on Windows system. And I've tried Android 7 and 6, which SDK version is 24 and 23. Still can't start an AVD. Is it because NDK version too high or something else?
Android 6 SDK:

Installed tools:

AVD:

Debug:

The deployment AVD "6" cannot be started.
Error while building/deploying project android (kit: Android Qt 6.8.0 Clang arm64-v8a)
When executing step "Deploy to Android device"

I tried a lower version of Android SDK.

I see what you posted, which is a driver issue. My problem is I can start x86_64 emulator on Windows 10, but not for arm64-v8a framework emulator on Windows 10.  Like I said, someone said Android sdk api under 28 should be ok with arm64-v8a emulator, but didn't work for me.

same question  This is the issue.

Hm, I see. Perhaps the folks at the Qt Forum could offer some insights? Just copy-paste this post there, and post an answer here if you get a solution, to benefit future readers.
